# "Cannot union streams of different types" error in flink when same pipeline works fine with dataflow?

Tags: apache-flink

I am running apache beam pipeline using flink runner which was running fine with dataflow. But gives below error when using flink:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. Cannot union streams of different types:
```

Is it because of some feature or funtion in pipeline that flink does not support?

Comment: How come it `was running fine with dataflow. But gives below error`? So, i assume it is not fine at all. Coul you paste the code?